# Manipulating datetimes

Tags: wordpress, datetime

I am fetching the start date for a specific event from an API. The response is a string in a known timezone (UTC) - different than the server's timezone (GMT+1). The date is definitely in the future.

If it's 'today', I'd like to display the time when the event starts.
If it's starting tomorrow, I'd like to display the day and the time when the event starts. But bot should be in the server's timezone.

I hacked it like this, but I find it terribly bad.

```
function manipulateEventDate($date)
{
    $now = new DateTime("now");
    $eventDate = new DateTime($date); // convert the string to DateTime
    $eventDate->modify('+ 1 hour'); // Manually convert it in the server's timezone

    if ($now->format('d') == $eventDate->format('d')) {
        return $eventDate->format('H:m');
    }

    return $eventDate->format('D H:i');
}
```

Output:

Event starts today: `18:00`

Event in the future: `Tue 11:00`

Any advice on how to deal with the timezones and solve the problem in a better way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your question you say "...different than the server's timezone".  If you truly mean the timezone that is specified for the server, then @BenCasey is correct.

However, I suspect that what you mean is *the timezone specified in "Settings > General > Timezone"* (i.e., the timezone for the WP site, rather than the timezone of the server).  If that is the case, then you'd want:

```
function
manipulateEventDate ($date)
{
    $siteTimezone = new DateTimeZone (get_option ('timezone_string')) ;

    $now = new DateTime ('now', $siteTimezone) ;
    $eventDate = new DateTime ($date, $siteTimezone) ;

    if ($now->format ('d') == $eventDate->format ('d')) {
        return ($eventDate->format ('H:m')) ;
        }

    return ($eventDate->format ('D H:i')) ;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can pass in the timezone to `new DateTime()` [[PHP Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php)]

if the date_default_timezone_set() function has been set, this will use that to load up that timezone.

```
function manipulateEventDate( $date ) {

    $dateTimezone = new DateTimeZone( date_default_timezone_get() );

    $now = new DateTime( "now" , $dateTimezone );
    $eventDate = new DateTime( $date , $dateTimezone );

    if ( $now->format( 'd' ) == $eventDate->format( 'd' ) ) {
        return $eventDate->format( 'H:m' );
    }

    return $eventDate->format( 'D H:i' );
}
```